# Riesz Representation Theorem for Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$$ X = \left\{ \{ a_{n} \}_{n} : a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}, \text{ and } \underset{n}{\text{lim }} a_{n} \text{ exists } \right\}  $$

State and prove a Representation Theorem for the dual of $X$.  In other words, you should define a particular set of linear functionals on $X$, and then show that any linear functional on $X$ must be in your set.

Here we mean by bounded linear functional some function $T$ from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha T(x) + \beta T(y)$$

and there exists $M$ such that for each $a_{n} \in X$,

$$ |T(a_{n})| \leq M || a_{n} ||_{\infty} $$

The norm on $X$ is $|| \cdot ||_{\infty} = \underset{n}{\text{sup }} | a_{n} |$ .

This one has me very confused.  I am thinking you are supposed to state and prove something similar to the Riesz Representation Theorem, only for $X$ instead of $L^{p}(E)$.  So something like, find a set $A$ of characteristic functions such that for each bounded linear functional $T$ on $X$, there exists a $\chi_{E_{i}} \in A $ such that

$$ T(\{ a_{n} \}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}*\chi_{E_{k}}  + \alpha \underset{n}{\text{ lim }} a_{n} $$

for all $a_{n} \in X$.  I don't think I have the form quite right... Please help :)

Comment: What norm do you have here? Does linear functional mean any $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x) = \lambda x$, or is some sort of continuity implied? Because if you mean continuity, you need to give a norm.

Comment: answered your question by editing the main question.

Comment: I don't think $T$ must have the form $\sum_n a_nb_n$. Consider $T(\{a_n\}) = \lim_n a_n$. I doubt this can be written as a sum like that...

Comment: You're correct.  That's why I am asking for help with the form.  I know it has something to do with summation but not exactly sure how it pans out.